# How to select and exclude data in self referencing table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have the following table structure in T-SQL

```
Stock
-----------------
Id, Name

Stock_Category
-----------------
StockId, CategoryId

Category
-----------------
Id, ParentCategoryId [Nullable], Name
```

I want to be able to execute an exclusion which traverses the entire map of the self referencing [Category] table. In other words I want to 'flatten' the Category self references and exclude via CategoryId. This is easy 'in code' (My case C#/Entity Framework) using recursion, a while loop or similar but is extremely slow.

Unfortunately I am lost as to how to build the same code as a stored procedure. I have considered that a cursor-set is likely required but even then I am not 100% sure how to structure it (i.e. do I create temp tables for every stock item? Surely there is a better way?).

Anyone kind enough to provide any guidance?

**EDIT:**

Given a Stock item which has an association to a category called [Cat], a subcategory called [Food] and a subcategory of [Food] called [Wet].

[Cat] > [Food] > [Wet]

When the input is the Id for [Cat] I want to output all stock items contained in [Cat] & [Food] & [Wet].

If the Input is the Id for [Food], I want to output all stock items contained in [Food] & [Wet].

And so forth.

Comment: What is your expected output ??

Comment: It would be great, if you could show us the expected output. Please provide the sample data in sql fiddle

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I have updated the question to hopefully clarify my desired output.

Comment: @MaximGershkovich, It is definitely possible to write a [Recursive query using Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) without any cursors. If you add some sample data to your question (few rows for each table illustrating possible variants) together with your expected results, it should be easy to write the actual query.